# jQuery load() method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am printing the ajax html response to div element **like-div** but the ajax html response is not working.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
ul.social-icon > li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.social-icon li a.like').click(function()
    { 
        var track = <?php echo $res_code; ?> ;
        $(".like-div").load("remove.php?keyword=delete&trackid="+track);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
$res_code = '6754567435';
?>
<ul class="social-icon">
              <li><a class="like" href="#123">Like</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="like-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to diaply the ajax response in div **like-div** on clicking the hyperlink **Like** but this is not showing anything in the div trait.

**remove.php**

```
<?php
$keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$trackid = $_REQUEST['trackid'];

echo $trackid;

?>
```

**remove.php** is the page from where response will come on sending the request.
what could be the reason that it is not showing the response in div?
Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: When you debugged this with various PHP and JavaScript debugging tools, what happened? Did the click event fire? Is there a syntax error? Is the jQuery library loaded? Did the AJAX request make it to the server? Is that the correct path to `remove.php`? Was there an error on the server? Even though this is a simple piece of code, there are many moving parts.

Comment: To me it looks like you're using `$res_code` before you've given it a value?

Comment: @Niklas: I think you're right. It would result in a JavaScript syntax error as `var track = ;` would be rendered in the browser, which would prevent the `load()` from executing.

Comment: @Niklas var track echo correct value..i confirm it by using alert after var track= <?php echo $res_code; ?> ; statement.

Comment: Is `remove.php` in the same path as the page you're displaying? Do you see "404" responses appear in the console? In any case, it's not advised to rely on relative paths.

Comment: @Ja͢ck remove.php is in the same directory where index.php exists. Both are different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the .load is incorrect. .load() is a short form for .post(). the parameters to be passed should be from the post request. Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.social-icon li a.like').click(function(){ 
        var track = <?php echo $res_code; ?> ;
        $(".like-div").load("remove.php", { "keyword":"delete","trackid":track});
    });
});
```

Comment: Whether it's POST or GET shouldn't matter because the script uses `$_REQUEST`; perhaps there was something OP didn't mention.

Comment: @Ja͢ck i don't know about that. Even using $_REQUEST is not recommended. relaying the data using $_POST is good in this case.

Comment: Regardless, it doesn't explain why this answer was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because `$res_code` is used before its defined. Move the following code block before the line `var track = <?php echo $res_code; ?> ;`:

```
 <?php
     $res_code = '6754567435';
 ?>
```

Comment: @Jindal But to me its not working. Is there any mechanism you are using  to initialize the value of `$res_code` variable?

Comment: $res_code variable value is coming dynamically from an array.

Comment: @Jindal In that case, can you share your full code using pastebin.com?

Comment: please check i sended with name "AJAX REQUEST".

Comment: @Jindal Please share the pastebin link

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
$(".like-div").load("remove.php?keyword=delete&trackid="+track, function( response) {

});
```